# How to use while loop in ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is my ajax

```
var vn = '*', dataString = 'vehicle_name='+ vn;

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getDesc.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            if(!data.error && data.success) {
             var vn = data.vehicleName, st = data.serviceType, o = data.others, rn = data.ref_no, rd = data.ref_date, rt = data.ref_type;
             var myTable1 ='<fieldset>' +
                 '<legend>Dashboard</legend><br>' +
                    '<table border="1" width="650">' +
                    '<tr bgcolor=#c0c0c0>' +
                            '<td width=100 align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Vehicle Name</b></font></td>' +
                            '<td width=80 align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Service Type</b></font></td>' +
                            '<td width=80 align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Others</b></font></td>' +
                            '<td width=100 align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Reference No.</b></font></td>' +
                            '<td width=80 align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Reference Date</b></font></td>' +
                            '<td width=80 align="center"><font face="helvetica"><b>Reference Type</b></font></td>' +
                        '</tr>' +

                        '<tr bgcolor=#c0c0c0>' +
                            '<td align=center>'+vn+'</td>' +
                            '<td align=center>'+st+'</td>' +
                            '<td align=center>'+o+'</td>' +
                            '<td align=center>'+rn+'</td>' +
                            '<td align=center>'+rd+'</td>' +
                            '<td align=center>'+rt+'</td>' +
                        '</tr>' +
                    '</table>' +
                 '</fieldset>';
                  $('#tabs-4').append(myTable1);

            } else {
                alert(data.errorMsg);
            }
        }
        });
```

Here is my PHP

```
<?PHP
include("db.classes.php");
$g = new DB();
$g->connection();

        if($_POST)
            {
                $vehicleName = $g->clean($_POST["vehicle_name"],1);

                $g->getAllDesc($vehicleName);
            }
$g->close();
 ?>
```

Here is my db.classes

```
public function getAllDesc($vehicleName)
    {
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        $sql = "select vehicle_name, service_type, others, ref_no, ref_date, ref_type from vehicle_services";

        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(json_encode(array('error' => 0,'errorMsg' => "MySQL query failed.")));

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {

            $output[] = array(
                'success' => 1,
                'vehicleName' => $row["vehicle_name"],
                'serviceType' => $row["service_type"],
                'others' => $row["others"],
                'ref_no' => $row["ref_no"],
                'ref_date' => $row["ref_date"],
                'ref_type' => $row["ref_type"]                 
                );

                echo json_encode($output);
        }

    }
```

And here is the response I get

> [{"success":1,"vehicleName":"JHE699","serviceType":"CHANGE
>   TIRE","others":"","ref_no":"14010001","ref_date":"2014-04-10","ref_type":"PRRIAR"}][{"success":1,"vehicleName":"JHE699","serviceType":"CHANGE
>   TIRE","others":"","ref_no":"14010001","ref_date":"2014-04-10","ref_type":"PRRIAR"},{"success":1,"vehicleName":"TOYOTA
>   86","serviceType":"TRUCK","others":"","ref_no":"1","ref_date":"2014-05-07","ref_type":"RR"}]

My first row gets duplicated and the table does not display. How do i pass the array so that my table would display?

Comment: why are you echoing the json output inside the while loop?

Comment: You mean the json_encode?

Comment: yes; because the json_encode is just echoing many times whereas should be just once for one array

Comment: I suggest that you properly instantiate the `$output` array above the while loop (`$output = array()`), then, instead of directly echoing the array, return the whole `$output` array after the while loop (`return $output`). Then you can use `$array =  $g->getAllDesc($vehicleName); echo json_encode($array);`. You might want to check that your database does not have a double up of the same vehicle.

Comment: Also, instead of a JSON reponse, try responding with an 'HTML Fragment'. Generate the HTML required for your form with PHP and return than, then your jQuery can just append the response to your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are not getting a printed table is because your JSON is invalid.

JSON responses are usually one JSON object, but in your case your while loop occurs 3 times, and you get 3 JSON objects. Your jQuery doesn't like the response so will error.

I suggest that you properly instantiate the `$output` array above the while loop (`$output = array()`), then, instead of directly echoing the array, return the whole `$output` array after the while loop (`return $output`). Then you can use:

```
$array = $g->getAllDesc($vehicleName); 
echo json_encode($array);.
```

You might want to check that your database does not have a double up of the same vehicle.